Why is LiveData postValue not updating my data in the background thread?
I'm working on an Android project where I receive data via USB in a background thread and update my LiveData object using postValue. I have a webView in the main thread. However, after calling postValue, my data is still null. Here's the relevant code:
MainActivity:


public class DebugActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private AircraftViewModel mModel;
    private OpenDroneIdDataManager dataManager;
    public LocationRequest locationRequest;
    public LocationCallback locationCallback;
    public FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationClient;
    private AircraftCesiumMapView mCesiumMapView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_debug);
        mModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(AircraftViewModel.class);
        dataManager = new OpenDroneIdDataManager(new OpenDroneIdDataManager.Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onNewAircraft(AircraftObject object) {
                mModel.setAllAircraft(dataManager.getAircraft());
            }
        });
        initialize();
    }

    private void initialize() {
        mModel.setAllAircraft(dataManager.getAircraft());

        mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
        locationRequest = new LocationRequest.Builder(10 * 1000) // 10 seconds
                .setPriority(Priority.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
                .setMinUpdateIntervalMillis(5 * 1000) // 5 seconds
                .build();

        locationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationResult(@NonNull LocationResult locationResult) {
                for (Location location : locationResult.getLocations()) {
                    if (location != null) {
                        dataManager.receiverLocation = location;
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        mCesiumMapView = (AircraftCesiumMapView) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapView);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (mFusedLocationClient != null)
            mFusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest, locationCallback, Looper.getMainLooper());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (mFusedLocationClient != null)
            mFusedLocationClient.removeLocationUpdates(locationCallback);
    }
}


AircraftMapview


public class AircraftCesiumMapView extends Fragment {
    private static final String TAG = "AircraftCesiumMapView";
    private WebView webView;
    private AircraftViewModel model;
    private final HashMap<AircraftObject, MapObserver> aircraftObservers = new HashMap<>();

    private final Util.DiffObserver<AircraftObject> allAircraftObserver = new Util.DiffObserver<AircraftObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onAdded(Collection<AircraftObject> added) {
            for (AircraftObject aircraftObject : added) {
                trackAircraft(aircraftObject);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onRemoved(Collection<AircraftObject> removed) {
            for (AircraftObject aircraftObject : removed) {
                stopTrackingAircraft(aircraftObject);
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_cesium_map, container, false);
        webView = view.findViewById(R.id.webView);
        setupWebView();
        setupModel();
        return view;
    }

    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    private void setupWebView() {
        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
        webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/cesium.html");
    }

    private void setupModel() {
        if (getActivity() == null)
            return;

        model = new ViewModelProvider(getActivity()).get(AircraftViewModel.class);
        model.getAllAircraft().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), allAircraftObserver);
    }

    private void trackAircraft(AircraftObject aircraftObject) {
        MapObserver observer = new MapObserver(aircraftObject);
        aircraftObservers.put(aircraftObject, observer);
    }

    private void stopTrackingAircraft(AircraftObject aircraftObject) {
        MapObserver observer = aircraftObservers.remove(aircraftObject);
        if (observer == null) return;
        observer.stop();
    }

    class MapObserver implements Observer<LocationData> {
        private final AircraftObject aircraft;

        MapObserver(AircraftObject active) {
            aircraft = active;
            aircraft.location.observe(AircraftCesiumMapView.this, this);
        }

        void stop() {
            aircraft.location.removeObserver(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable LocationData locationData) {
            // Handle location updates, e.g., update WebView with new position
        }
    }
}

UsbSerial.java


public class UsbSerial {
    private static final String ACTION_USB_PERMISSION = "com.org.opendroneid.android.app.USB_PERMISSION";
    private final Context context;
    private final UsbManager usbManager;
    private UsbSerialPort usbSerialPort;
    private SerialInputOutputManager usbIoManager;
    private final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    private final StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
    private final OpenDroneIdDataManager dataManager;
    private int msgCounter_global;

    public UsbSerial(Context context, OpenDroneIdDataManager dataManager) {
        this.context = context;
        this.usbManager = (UsbManager) context.getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);
        this.dataManager = dataManager;
    }

    public void startUsbCommunication() {
        List<UsbSerialDriver> availableDrivers = UsbSerialProber.getDefaultProber().findAllDrivers(usbManager);
        if (availableDrivers.isEmpty()) {
            Log.d("USB", "No USB devices found");
            return;
        }

        for (UsbSerialDriver driver : availableDrivers) {
            UsbDevice device = driver.getDevice();
            if (!usbManager.hasPermission(device)) {
                // Request permission
            } else {
                connectToDevice(device);
            }
        }
    }

    private void connectToDevice(UsbDevice device) {
        UsbSerialDriver driver = UsbSerialProber.getDefaultProber().probeDevice(device);
        if (driver == null) {
            Log.d("USB", "No driver for device");
            return;
        }

        List<UsbSerialPort> ports = driver.getPorts();
        if (ports.isEmpty()) {
            Log.d("USB", "No ports available on device");
            return;
        }
        usbSerialPort = ports.get(0); // Use the first port for the dev kit

        try {
            usbSerialPort.open(usbManager.openDevice(device));
            usbSerialPort.setParameters(115200, 8, UsbSerialPort.STOPBITS_1, UsbSerialPort.PARITY_NONE);
            startIoManager();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("USB", "Error setting up device: " + e.getMessage(), e);
            try {
                usbSerialPort.close();
            } catch (IOException e2) {
                // Ignore.
            }
            usbSerialPort = null;
        }
    }

    private void startIoManager() {
        if (usbSerialPort != null) {
            usbIoManager = new SerialInputOutputManager(usbSerialPort, new SerialInputOutputManager.Listener() {
                @Override
                public void onNewData(byte[] data) {
                    buffer.append(new String(data, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
                    if (buffer.toString().contains("\n")) {
                        String completeMessage = extractCompleteMessage(buffer);
                        String[] result = parseSerialInput(completeMessage);
                        if (result != null && result.length == 5) {
                            result[2] = result[2].replaceAll(" \\(random\\)", "");
                            onReceiveData(result[0], result[1], result[2], result[3], result[4]);
                        }
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onRunError(Exception e) {
                    Log.d("USB", "Runner stopped. " + e.getMessage());
                }
            });
            executor.submit(usbIoManager);
        }
    }

    private String[] parseSerialInput(String message) {
        // The actual implementation is omitted
        return null;
    }

    private void onReceiveData(String hexData, String numMsg, String macAddr, String rssi, String transportType) {
        String[] messages = splitFullHexData(hexData, Integer.parseInt(numMsg), transportType);
        long currentTimeMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();
        LogMessageEntry logMessageEntry = new LogMessageEntry();

        for (String message : messages) {
            byte[] data = hexToBytes(message);
            dataManager.receiveDataUsb(data, macAddr, rssi, currentTimeMillis, logMessageEntry, transportType, msgCounter_global);
        }
    }

    private byte[] hexToBytes(String hexData) {
        
        return data;
    }

    private String[] splitFullHexData(String hexData, int numberOfMessages, String tpType) {
        // The actual implementation is omitted
        return null;
    }

    private String extractCompleteMessage(StringBuilder buffer) {
        // The actual implementation is omitted
        return null;
    }

    public void onDestroy() {
        if (usbIoManager != null) {
            usbIoManager.stop();
        }
        if (usbSerialPort != null) {
            try {
                usbSerialPort.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // Ignore.
            }
        }
    }
}


datamanager


public class OpenDroneIdDataManager {
    public final ConcurrentHashMap<Long, AircraftObject> aircraft = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    public android.location.Location receiverLocation;
    private final Callback callback;
    private static final String TAG = "OpenDroneIdDataManager";

    public static class Callback {
        public void onNewAircraft(AircraftObject object) {}
    }

    public OpenDroneIdDataManager(Callback callback) {
        this.callback = callback;
    }

    public ConcurrentHashMap<Long, AircraftObject> getAircraft() {
        return aircraft;
    }

    public void receiveDataUsb(byte[] data, String macAddress, String rssi, long timestamp, LogMessageEntry logMessageEntry, String transportType, int msgCounter) {
        long macAddressLong = macAddressToLong(macAddress);
        OpenDroneIdParser.Message<?> message = OpenDroneIdParser.parseDataUSB(data, 0, timestamp, logMessageEntry, receiverLocation, msgCounter);

        if (message == null) return;

        receiveDataUsbHelper(timestamp, macAddress, macAddressLong, Integer.parseInt(rssi), message, logMessageEntry, transportType);
    }

    private void receiveDataUsbHelper(long timestamp, String macAddress, long macAddressLong, int rssi, OpenDroneIdParser.Message<?> message, LogMessageEntry logMessageEntry, String transportType) {
        boolean newAircraft = false;
        AircraftObject ac = aircraft.get(macAddressLong);
        if (ac == null) {
            ac = createNewAircraft(macAddress, macAddressLong);
            newAircraft = true;
        }

        long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Connection connection = ac.getConnection();
        if (connection == null) {
            connection = new Connection();
            ac.setConnection(connection);
        }
        connection.msgDelta = currentTime - connection.lastSeen;
        connection.lastSeen = currentTime;
        connection.rssi = rssi;
        connection.transportType = transportType;
        connection.setTimestamp(timestamp);
        connection.setMsgVersion(message.header.version);

        Log.d(TAG, "Before postValue: " + ac.getConnection());
        ac.connection.postValue(connection);
        Log.d(TAG, "After postValue: " + ac.getConnection());

        if (newAircraft) {
            aircraft.put(macAddressLong, ac);
            callback.onNewAircraft(ac);
        }

        handleMessages(ac, message);
    }

    private AircraftObject createNewAircraft(String macAddress, long macAddressLong) {
        AircraftObject ac = new AircraftObject(macAddressLong);
        Connection connection = new Connection();
        connection.firstSeen = System.currentTimeMillis();
        connection.macAddress = macAddress;
        ac.connection.postValue(connection);
        return ac;
    }

    private void handleMessages(AircraftObject ac, OpenDroneIdParser.Message<?> message) {
        // Handle different message types here
    }

    private long macAddressToLong(String macAddress) {
        return Long.parseLong(macAddress.replace(":", ""), 16);
    }
}


I'm expecting the Log would not return null
ac.connection.postValue(connection);
Log.d(TAG, "After postValue: " + ac.getConnection());

I tried handler and syncrhonize and those seems not to work
